# Run the for loop only once Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

```
   total_Route = zeros(4,4);
   tmp = evalin('base', 't'); % i initialise t in the Workspace with the value 1

   if(tmp==5)
   tmp=1;
   end

    total_Route(tmp,1) = Distance_Traveled_CM;
    total_Route(tmp,2) = Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM;
    total_Route(tmp,3) = Nebenaggregate_Verbrauch_Real_CM;
    total_Route(tmp,4) = t;

    Total_Distance_Traveled_CM = sum(total_Route(:,1));
    set(handles.edit3, 'string',Total_Distance_Traveled_CM);

    Total_Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM = sum(total_Route(:,2));
    set(handles.edit4, 'string',Total_Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM);

    Total_Nebenaggregate_Verbrauch_Real_CM = sum(total_Route(:,3));
    set(handles.edit5, 'string',Total_Nebenaggregate_Verbrauch_Real_CM);

    %% Index
    set(handles.edit15, 'string',tmp);

    assignin('base', 't', tmp + 1);  % with this line i can increment "t" after each pass
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Sorry that I did not explain my problem well.

@Sardar_Usama I want to run the loop only once but `t` should be incremented after each time I click on my Button.

@ Sembei Norimaki `end` is at the end of my codes, have forgotten to write it in my question 
@Patrik & @Dennis Jaheruddin let me explain my problem again

I created a Matrix with 4×4 Elements with the Goal to save the results of each my Variable (`Total_Distance_Traveled_CM`, `Total_Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM` etc...) after each Simulation in the element of my Matrix (See image below).

[image]

I want by pressing a button (on my GUI) to get always the sum of each Column.

### Example

The first pass: `t = 1`--> `Distance_Traveled(1,1)` is 900 the GUI will take through clicking on the Button, the sum of the first column (which is 900+0+0+0) and write it in a static test.

The second pass `t = 2`--> `Distance_traveled(2,1)` is 800 the GUI will take the sum of the first column (which is 900+800+0+0) and write it in a static test and the same thing should happen with the other column.

This should continue until `t = 4` i.e. until it does the same thing for each column, then it should reset.

I hope, I have explained my problem better this time and I apologize for my bad English.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you want to run the loop only once then what's the purpose of using a loop? and what do you mean by *"i" should be incremented after each pass*?

Comment: Where does the for loop end? In Matlab you need and `end` for the loops.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not a clue what you want to do. You need to give us more than this.

Comment: @EBH note that "until" has a single l in it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, they were [so many](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39247195/3), I couldn't catch them all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code fragment the for loop is only called once.

However, the contents of the for loop are ran for four times. (first for i=1 then for 1=2 etc..)

If you only want to run one of these options the solution is very simple:

```
i = 1
yourLoopContent
```

If i is always 0 the first time, and you always want to run it for the current i, it would also be simple:

```
yourLoopContent
i = i+1;
```

However if i may not be set properly the first time, things get messy. This is because i is by default defined as the square root of minus 1. 
Therefore I would recommend you to use a different letter like t instead. Then you could do this:

```
if ~exists(t)
    t=0;
end
yourLoopContent %Everywhere using t instead of i
t = t+1;
```

In general you may want to avoid i as an index to stay clear of complex number issues.

Comment: sorry that i did not explain my problem well.
@Sardar_Usama i want to run the loop only once but "i" should be incremented only once after each simulation

Comment: @Sami Have you looked at the three suggestions in my answer? Based on your comment I would say that the second or third should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ Dennis Jaheruddin Thank u  Dennis for the Quick response.
I tried to descibe my problem better, hope that it is now understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly, but it seems to me that what you look for is a cumulative sum. This can be done either buy summing on `1:t` or by using [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html?searchHighlight=cumsum). I'm not sure why you use a loop, but if this is only for the summing then `cumsum` can replace that.

Here is some example in your code:

```
total_Route = zeros(4,4);
% I commented below what is not part of the question
for t = 1:4
    total_Route(t,:) = [Distance_Traveled_CM,
        Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM,
        Nebenaggregate_Verbrauch_Real_CM,
        t]; 

    % the following line compute the comulative sum from the top of each
    % column to every element in it, so cs_total_Route(3,2) is like
    % sum(total_Route(1:3,2)):
    cs_total_Route = cumsum(total_Route);

    Total_Distance_Traveled_CM = cs_total_Route(t,1); % OR sum(total_Route(1:t,1))
%     set(handles.edit3, 'string',Total_Distance_Traveled_CM);

    Total_Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM = cs_total_Route(t,2); % OR sum(total_Route(1:t,2))
%     set(handles.edit4, 'string',Total_Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM);

    Total_Nebenaggregate_Verbrauch_Real_CM = cs_total_Route(t,3); % OR sum(total_Route(1:t,3))
%     set(handles.edit5, 'string',Total_Nebenaggregate_Verbrauch_Real_CM);

%     set(handles.edit15, 'string',t);
end
```

And here is a quick look on what `cumsum` does (with some random numbers for `total_Route`):

```
total_Route =
          671       4.6012       1.0662            1
          840       3.6475      0.58918            2
          354       8.6056       2.1313            3
          893       4.1362       2.0118            4
cs_total_Route =
          671       4.6012       1.0662            1
         1511       8.2487       1.6554            3
         1865       16.854       3.7867            6
         2758       20.991       5.7985           10
```

Is this what you looked for?

Comment: you have filled the table with random numbers, in my case when(t=0) is the Table empty.
i get after each Simulation Values of my Variable (Total_Distance_Traveled_CM, Total_Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM) in the workspace, i want to save those VALUE in the first cell of each column and bild the sum of the cells off each columns. PS: the other cells still empty and they will be filled with values in the next pass off "t". important is to remenber the last values from the last pass and to return the sum after each time the cells are filles with values.
did u get my point ?

Comment: And i was hoping to increment "t", by pushing my button.
(incrementing "t" by one every time when the button is pressed untill t = 4 and it should be reset at 1 again )
which mean when t=1 then the values of my Variable will be filled in the first cells of each my columns.
when t = 2  the values of my Variable will be filled in the second cells of each my columns.
ect untill t = 4 and i want by every pass to get the sum of my Columns.

Comment: The random variables were just for the example. See my edit for your case.

Comment: in this case, the for loop will be runing 4 times by clicking once on my button

Comment: Your goal isn't so clear to me, but maybe you don't need a loop, just define `t = 1` at the start, and after every click on the button increase `t` by 1. I would suggest warping all this in a function, that is called when the button is pressed, something like: `total_Route = get_values(total_Route,Distance_Traveled_CM, Hauptantrieb_Verbrauchte_Energie_CM, Nebenaggregate_Verbrauch_Real_CM, t)`. So `t` is passed to the function along with `total_Route`, and `total_Route` is returned filled with another line. This sounds closer to the desired behaviour?

Comment: @ EBH u have right, i dont need a loop at all. I edit my code  (See Question again) Now i can increment tmp or %t after each time i click on my button. but the code still not doing what i want.
by the first pass i get my Value in the correspondin cells in each off each Colomun --> so far no problem
but by the second pass  when i want to have the sum i dont get the right results because i think that my code, doesnt storged the value off the first pass and the same thing is happening in the third and fourth pass.
cann u tell me why ? do u have a idea how i can make it works ?

Comment: @Sami you have to add somewhere at the end `tmp = tmp+1`, otherwise you constantly updating the same row in `total_Route`. It is really hard to follow (and strongly not recommended) a code that uses `evalin` and `assignin`, but those lines would be my first ones to check.

Comment: @Sami maybe you don't need all this and you can compute `t = 1:4` all at once, and just show them to the user one by one (when pressing a button)?

Comment: i can't Unfortunately  work with the for-loop in my case. im going to use ur advice and try to fix it. i will let u know if its works.  thank u so much again for ur help